# Fetch 1 column value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following column in my database: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMYJC.png

How can I make it so it will read that column and write `example.com` to my site?:

```
echo "Your website: " . $website;
```

Note that I'm a starter with php.

Comment: have you read mysql query?

Comment: It looks like you need to study more on how to interface with databases. Here's some reading on [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) that you can do.

Comment: It must be phpmyadmin ?

Comment: @MariM What's it called? English isn't my native language and that's one book of a page. Can you provide me with a link to the right direction?

Comment: What about learning the basics of using PHP + MySQL? There are plenty of tutorials and openbooks online in a plenty of languages.

Comment: @CarlJohnson If you know SQL language, take a look at MySQLi and PDO, if you don't know SQL language, start by learning it

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to PHP, first learn the database connectivity through PHP
check this out : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

After successful database connection, try how to query on database through PHP
check this out : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Sample Code :

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $mysqli->real_query("SELECT website FROM my_table");
    $res = $mysqli->use_result();

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo " Website = " . $row['website'] . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: At least you provide me a sample instead of a book with links, thank you for helping, I got it. Just a question, can you combine mysql with mysqli?

Comment: ideally you should not do this, from security point of view as mysql is deprecated, so I will suggest you to use mysqli only in all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

an example is this :

```
$query = "SELECT website FROM TableName WHERE YourCondition";

    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
        do {
            /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    echo "Your website: ". $row[0]; 
                }
                $result->free();
            }
```

Check out `mysqli::multi_query` here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

And read the full documentation of `mysqli` here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to establish a connection to your MySQL database. I recommend using PDO for this. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for more info on that.

To establish a connection with PDO, try the following:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME',$username,$password);
```

Then write a query to grab the data from your database. In your example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT website FROM your_table_name';
```

Then execute the query:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$website_list = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$website_list` now contains an associative array of all the websites saved in that column.

Then to print them to your website:

```
foreach($website_list as $site){
    print 'Your website: '.$site['website'].'<br/>';
}
```